# Using roslaunch to run distributed systems over ssh

Tags: ros, roslaunch, remote

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm just trying to make my distributed ROS system run with one single command for the first time. I went through [roslaunch/Architecture](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roslaunch/Architecture) and [roslaunch tips for larger projects](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roslaunch/Tutorials/Roslaunch%20tips%20for%20larger%20projects) which helped me a lot, but not enough.

My system is disributed over 2 machines, say Alpha and Beta, the second being localhost (authorized_keys defined, hostnames checked, communication works flawlessly). So my launchfile looks like this:

```
<launch>
  <machine name="alpha" address="alpha" user="alpha_user" 
    ros-root="/correct/path/on/alpha/machine" 
    ros-package-path="/very/true/package/path" default="true" />
  <machine name="beta" address="beta" user="beta_user" 
    ros-root="$(env ROS_ROOT)" 
    ros-package-path="$(env ROS_PACKAGE_PATH)" default="false" />

  <node pkg="hokuyo_node" type="hokuyo_node" name="hokuyo_node" output="screen">
    <param name="frame_id" value="/laser"/>
    <param name="port" value="/dev/ttyACM0"/>
  </node>

  <node pkg="laser_scan_matcher" type="laser_scan_matcher_node"
    name="laser_scan_matcher_node" output="screen">
  </node>

  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="laser_link" 
    args="0.0 0.0 0.10 0.0 0.0 0.0 /base_link /laser 40" />

  <node pkg="gmapping" type="slam_gmapping" name="gmapping" 
    output="screen" machine="beta">
    <param name="odom_frame" value="/world" />
  </node>
</launch>
```

Running this on beta yields:

```
started roslaunch server http://beta:59751/
remote[alpha-0] starting roslaunch
remote[alpha-0]: creating ssh connection to alpha:22, user[alpha_user]
remote[alpha-0]: ssh connection created

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /gmapping/odom_frame
 * /rosdistro
 * /laser_scan_matcher_node/max_iterations
 * /laser_scan_matcher_node/use_odom
 * /hokuyo_node/max_ang
 * /rosversion
 * /hokuyo_node/port
 * /laser_scan_matcher_node/use_imu
 * /laser_scan_matcher_node/fixed_frame
 * /hokuyo_node/frame_id
 * /laser_scan_matcher_node/use_alpha_beta
 * /hokuyo_node/min_ang

MACHINES
 * beta
 * alpha

NODES
  /
    hokuyo_node (hokuyo_node/hokuyo_node)
    laser_scan_matcher_node (laser_scan_matcher/laser_scan_matcher_node)
    laser_link (tf/static_transform_publisher)
    gmapping (gmapping/slam_gmapping)

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [3002]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

setting /run_id to 3bf5a6de-307c-11e1-ba58-00216a2f5558
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [3017]
started core service [/rosout]
process[gmapping-2]: started with pid [3020]
[alpha-0]: launching nodes...
[alpha-0]: auto-starting new master
[alpha-0]: process[master]: started with pid [1433]
[alpha-0]: ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311
[alpha-0]: setting /run_id to 3bf5a6de-307c-11e1-ba58-00216a2f5558
[alpha-0]: process[hokuyo_node-1]: started with pid [1452]
[alpha-0]: process[laser_scan_matcher_node-2]: started with pid [1453]
[alpha-0]: process[laser_link-3]: started with pid [1454]
[alpha-0]: ... done launching nodes
```

I think there are two `roscore's` being spawned which don't know about each other. I'm guessing it, because running `rosgraph` locally after changing:

```
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://alpha:11311
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://beta:11311
```

returns only nodes run on the particular computer, and because of the suspicious lines above:

```
[alpha-0]: launching nodes...
[alpha-0]: auto-starting new master
[alpha-0]: process[master]: started with pid [1433]
[alpha-0]: ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311
```

Testing what processes are really being spawned on both machines with:

```
ps aux | grep ros
```

yields: [ps_alpha](http://pastebin.com/ELvWy1jz) [ps_beta](http://pastebin.com/xsngBh5n).

Where do I tell ROS to only spawn one `roscore` (preferably on the remote machine, i.e. beta)? Or how do I else configure the system correctly?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12434/using-roslaunch-to-run-distributed-systems-over-ssh/) by [tom](https://answers.ros.org/users/58/tom/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1079 on 2011-12-22

Post score: 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@kwc confirmed two bugs which caused the above mentioned behavior, the tickets are:

- https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/ticket/3801
- https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/ticket/3802

The problem only occurs when `ROS_MASTER_URI` is set to `localhost` on the machine where a distributed ROS system is being launched from. It is desired to set `ROS_MASTER_URI` depending on `hostname` instead (the bug is that roslaunch doesn't catch when you fail to set this, and compounds it by starting an extra remote core).

Example: Say your local system's `hostname` is beta and you're using `roslaunch` to start a distributed ROS system on `alpha` (remote) and `beta` (local) - as in the launchfile cited in question. Per default, `ROS_MASTER_URI` on `beta` would be:

```
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311
```

which doesn't get cought by the system and gets falsely set on  `alpha` too, and in effect two `roscore`'s are being started which don't know about each other. Instead, setting:

```
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://beta:11311
```

on `beta` before executing launchfile causes ROS_MASTER_URI on both machines to be set to http://beta:11311 which is correct.

---

Originally posted by [tom](https://answers.ros.org/users/58/tom/) with karma: 1079 on 2011-12-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 8

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tom](https://answers.ros.org/users/58/tom/) on 2011-12-30**:
@kwc: Corrected.

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2011-12-30**:
Correction: setting your ROS_MASTER_URI to http://beta:11311 is not a temporary workaround, it's what you're always supposed to do.  The bug is that roslaunch doesn't catch when you fail to set this, and compounds it by starting an extra core.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

roslaunch cannot spawn multiple roscores, so it sounds like something else is going on.

It sounds strange that you say you are using  tags inside of nodes.  You cannot use a  inside of a  tag.  You must use the machine attribute.

http://ros.org/wiki/roslaunch/XML/node

EDIT: also should add, roslaunch has *no* capability to launch roscores on remote systems, so if there is one running remotely, it did not start it.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-12-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tom](https://answers.ros.org/users/58/tom/) on 2011-12-28**:
Well, isn't it nice to reveal features one would think aren't already there and need to be written yet are actually provided? Even if they still need some further tuning :). You'll find my full logs on your email at wg.

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2011-12-28**:
You are correct, I am wrong, there are two masters running, which is a bug, not a feature.  There is an interesting bug in the ps output that you put on pastebin (server URI is invalid).  I cannot find any code path that causes it.  Can you "roscd log" and upload roslaunch-*.log somewhere?

**Comment by [tom](https://answers.ros.org/users/58/tom/) on 2011-12-27**:
Thanks for your time @kwc. Pasted the suggested outputs above. It still seems to me there are two roscores being spawned... - I'm on Diamondback, built from source, maybe this leaves a hint.

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2011-12-27**:
I suggest you investigate what processes are actually running on the remote machine with tools like "ps", e.g. "ps aux | grep ros"

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2011-12-27**:
roslaunch cannot start a core on a remote machine. The code to do so has not been written yet.  If there is a core running on the remote machine, roslaunch did not start it.

**Comment by [tom](https://answers.ros.org/users/58/tom/) on 2011-12-26**:
I edited my question and added some more details. It seems to me there are actually two masters being spawned and   ROS_MASTER_URI set to  localhost on both machines.

**Comment by [tom](https://answers.ros.org/users/58/tom/) on 2011-12-22**:
Right, edited my question. I meant an attribute, just called it wrong.